# Where do active display converters get their power from?

Tags: converter, computers

I have bought a mini Display Port to HDMI/VGA/DVI active converter.
It works on VGA, but VGA is broken [dimmed screen? and I don't know how to fix that] on the monitor (so my only option left is HDMI).

I went and connected the HDMI, changed input on the monitor to HDMI and behold.... nothing. I figured it could be because the monitor isn't supplying power to this active converter so I might solder a few wires to it and take a power adapter (appropriately rated) and hook it up. So here I am, with the probes in my hand, figuring out which HDMI connectors should provide the power (I don't know). But befor I am going to potentially destroy this device, how can I determine where it (should) get its power from?

Top:
[image]
Bottom:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both HDMI and DisplayPort have a +5 V DC line so most likely that's what powers it.

And VGA does **not** have a +5 V DC line.